# iptables - How to allow all connections to the local lan?

Tags: iptables

What's the simplest way to express "allow all connections to the local lan" for iptables output?

Including connections to `192.*`, `172.*`, `10.*`, etc.

Can all of this compressed within a single rule?

Comment: does using the comma separated list of (for example) 'iptables -t filter -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT' not work?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ipset`

```
ipset create locallan hash:net
ipset add locallan 192.168.0.0/16
ipset add locallan 172.16.0.0/16
ipset add locallan 10.0.0.0/8

iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set locallan src -j ACCEPT
```

Would allow connections from those ranges to the server with that rule.

Answer (score 1):

As llua said, using `ipset`. However, you'll probably want to make this persist through reboots; ipsets are stored in memory otherwise.

`ipset save > /etc/ipset.conf`, then enable the ipset service so it recreates the set on reboots (on Arch systems, at least, which provide an `ipset.service` systemd file).

Add to `/etc/rc.local` the line `ipset restore -f /etc/ipset.conf` on most other Linux systems.

See the always-excellent [Arch wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ipset#Making_ipset_persistent) for more.